# Stored procedure for counting file types

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have table called tbl_upload which stores the data of uploaded file into it, with the columns of Filename, filetype, filesize, serial etc.

```
 | FileName|Filetype|Filesize|Serial|
 |    a    | doc    |   1232 |  1   |
 |    b    | txt    |   1232 |  2   |
 |    c    | pdf    |   321  |  4   |
 |    d    | xls    |    41  |  5   |
 |    e    | rtf    |    23  |  6   |
```

like this so on.....

There might be file types of around 8 to 10 including odt, html, xml etc...

On a page i would like to show all of types in a graph using jqxChart, which need its data source in 'json'or 'array'or 'xml' types.
So i need to get the total no.of doc files, total no.of txt files, no.of rtf etc ..
I wrote a SP as

```
       ALTER proc [dbo].[GetFiles] @Pdf int out, @doc int out, @odt int out, @txt int  out
    as
    begin
    select @Pdf= COUNT (*)  from tbl_Uploads where Filetype='xml' 
    select @doc=COUNT (*)  from tbl_Uploads where Filetype='doc'
    select @txt=COUNT (*)  from tbl_Uploads where Filetype='txt'
    select @odt=COUNT (*)  from tbl_Uploads where Filetype='odt'
   ...so on


end
```

Is this a good approach or is there any better ways than this?? I just want total no. of each file type...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try getting the results in a table and then in your client add them to variables.

```
SELECT Filetype,
       COUNT(*) AS TypeCount
FROM tbl_Uploads
GROUP BY Filetype
```

Comment: No, make your sp return that.